# MySql replace range of characters in VARCHAR data

Tags: mysql, replace

I am trying to remove everything between the first char in a field and a colon.  Was trying INSERT but could only find how to do that via char count but this varies from 14-16

was hoping to do something like:

```
select INSERT(column, 1, ':', '') from table.
```

Comment: Please post sample data and wanted result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Column,LOCATE(':',Column));
```

SIMPLE TEST

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('A long Str:ing',LOCATE(':','A long Str:ing'));
```

Result

```
:ing
```